# Most elegant way to modify an IP by a given network in Python

Tags: python, string, networking, ip, netmask

I'm looking for an elegant piece of code to do the following:

I'm given an IP str, like `152.23.10.8` and a network string `4.0.0.0\8`, I want my method to modify the IP so it will fit the network, in the above example, the output will be `4.23.10.8`.

I want it to support not just `0,8,16,24,32` but also values in the middle like `20`.

This is not a difficult problem - but I'm looking for a good looking way to do that...

Comment: How have you currently solved it?

Comment: What logic brings you to turn 152.23.10.8/32 into 4.23.10.8/32 because of 4.0.0.0/8?